# Debian server loses network connection after 7 days

Tags: debian

I am running a debian box and i use it as a sandbox for developing web applications etc. In 7-8 days the server loses all network connectivity and i have to reboot it by hand, it cannot get connection and i cannot SSH to my server. I have tried things like restarting networking and for this week i have disabled a few features of the server's NIC (tx checksum). Could this be a dns issue?.

Comment: While DNS is the culprit in far too many problems, this appears to be a very random guess in this case. Do you have any log file entries from around where you had to restart the machine?

Comment: Did you take a look at `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` after you can ssh?

Comment: Fixed IP on the server? How do you connect to it? Try using the IP.

Comment: I connect by IP, its a local box. I think DHCP might be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be DNS.  The way to test this is to ssh to the IP address, not the name.  If you can get to the IP address but not the name, then DNS is partially guilty.

Do you get the address with DHCP?  If so, how long is the DHCP lease?

Comment: I cannot form ssh connection to the IP address when this happens. I think DHCP might be the culprit. After a bit of searching on the subject it seems my /etc/network/interfaces might be missing something related to this (auto eth0, iface eth0 dhcp).

Comment: SOLVED! DHCP lease was expiring. Added auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp to /etc/network/interfaces